# Сортировка по файлам

Tags: сортировка, c++

Есть 600 файлов в папке, каждый файл представляет собой список из 13  столбцов: год, месяц,день, температура, а также остальные 9 малоозначающих столбцов данных. Задача-найти среднегодовое значение температуры для каждого файла (т.е. для каждого объекта) и вывести эти значения в другой файл. Для нахождения среднегодовых значений температуры для каждого отдельного файла программу я написал, вот она:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

//  1946 12 30 0 -519 0 -490 0 9999 9 0 2 0

typedef struct {
    int year;
    int month;
    int day;
    int param4;
    int param5;
    int param6;
    int t;
    int param8;
    int param9;
    int param10;
    int param11;
    int param12;
    int param13;
} FILE_DATA;

int l = 1;
int sum = 1;
int k = 1;
double arifmet = 0;
double arifmet2 = 0;
int current_sum = 0;
int current_year = 0;

int main()
{
    int i;                        // Счётчик
    int n = 0;                    // Будет содержать число ситанных строк
    FILE_DATA *pList = NULL;      // Указатель на массив структур FILE_DATA
    FILE *file = fopen("U24763", "rb");        // Инициализируем поток чтения
    FILE *file2 = fopen("input2.txt", "w");
    FILE *file3 = fopen("Srednee_Zna4enie_temperatur", "w");

    if (file == NULL)
        printf("Error open input.txtn");
    else {
        // Выделяем память под первую структуру массива
        pList = (FILE_DATA *) malloc(sizeof(FILE_DATA));
        for (n = 0; !feof(file);) {
            // Мало кто знает, но fscanf возвращает
            // число считанных параметров
            if (13 ==                // Как раз проверяем все ли 13 параметров считали
                fscanf(file, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %dn", &pList[n].year, &pList[n].month, &pList[n].day, &pList[n].param4, &pList[n].param5, &pList[n].param6, &pList[n].t, &pList[n].param8, &pList[n].param9, &pList[n].param10, &pList[n].param11, &pList[n].param12, &pList[n].param13)
                )
            {
                // Если чтение успешно печатает n-ую структуру
                printf("%04d %02d %02d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %dn", pList[n].year, pList[n].month, pList[n].day, pList[n].param4, pList[n].param5, pList[n].param6, pList[n].t, pList[n].param8, pList[n].param9, pList[n].param10, pList[n].param11, pList[n].param12, pList[n].param13);
                if (pList[n].t != 9999) {
                    if (pList[n].year != current_year) {
                        fprintf(file2, "%04d %d %d %.4f n", current_year, current_sum, l, arifmet);
                        current_sum = 0;
                        l = 1;
                        current_year = pList[n].year;
                    } else {
                        current_sum += pList[n].t;
                        l++;
                    }
                    sum += pList[n].t;
                    k++;
                    arifmet = current_sum / l;
                    arifmet2 = sum / k;
                    fprintf(file3, "%.4f %d %d", arifmet2, sum, k);
                }

                n++;                // увеличиваем счётчик структур
                pList = (FILE_DATA *)
                    realloc        // Увеличиваем память под массив структур
                    ((void *) pList, (1 + n) * sizeof(FILE_DATA)        // одновременно
                    );
            }

        }
        //           fwrite(file2,arifmet);
        fclose(file);
        fclose(file2);
        fclose(file3);
        if (n == 0)
            printf("File input.txt not contain correct datan");
        else {
            printf("Totlal count of read structures %dn", n);
            // здесь у нас массив структур из n элементов
            // далее делам с ним что душе угодно
        }
    }
    printf("Enter any key for exitn");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Вопрос: как ее дописать, чтобы файлы не вручную вводить?

Comment: @kuziashag85, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: А вообще, в Boost'е есть то, что вам должно подойти:

http://www.solarix.ru/for_developers/cpp/boost/filesystem/ru/index.shtml

Comment: Если намерены регулярно заниматься обработкой данных подобного рода, рекомендую освоить какой-нибудь высокоуровневый сценарный язык, типа Python или Perl. Программы будут писаться в несколько раз быстрее и без вскипания мозгов. А Си использовать для разного рода сложных и долгих вычислений. Говорю из собственного опыта.

Comment: И еще: это случайно не база метеорологических данных, происходящая из Обнинска?

Comment: mikillskegg, может быть да, может быть нет. Я без понятия=) Моя задача была рассортировать данные, а затем построить изолинии в mapinfo  с товарищем. Т.к.  товарищ понимает в программировании также как я в балете-приходиться разбираться самому=)

Comment: Алексей, буду иметь ввиду

Comment: Где работаете, коллеги?

Comment: Институт глобального климата и экологии=))при Росгидромете=))) в городе Москва=) Насчет Perla буду иметь ввиду=)) Я имею честь общаться с геоэкологом?=) Или геодезистом?=)) Вообще мы тут флуд разводим=))) Можем в личку написать=)))

Comment: Вы имеете дело с с.н.с. из лаборатории проф. Семенова. О таком слышали?

Comment: Из ИГКЭ? Т.е. директора нашего института?=) Как интересно встретиться на просторах интернета=)))

Answer (score 1):

[@kuziashag85](/users/8395/kuziashag85), Вы наверное уже решили свою задачу. Если нет, то просто используйте sh (или другой скриптовый язык) для вызова Вашей программы для каждого файла.

Не очень понятно зачем нужна печать и вывод в файл input2. Если это не нужно, то чуток переделайте программу (чтение файла из stdin, запись в stdout).

Тогда на sh можно написать очень простой скрипт (например)

```
mkdir ../results; for i in *; do your_prog <$i >../results/$i-sum; done
```

И вы получите Ваши среднегодовые файлы в каталоге ../resuls